# Why comes error when set a attribute to a cls type in Ryven?

Tags: python

(English is not my native language)

It is a start use about `Ryven`, I just do `pip install ryven` and run `ryven` as the document say:

https://ryven.org/guide#/?id=flows

The version of python is 3.10.1 on linux.Version of `ryven` is 3.1.0.

When I click the button:  `CREATE NEW PROJECT`.Error comes(just on linux,not come on windows):

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/mini_codes/ry_ven.py", line 14, in <module>
    ryven.run_ryven()
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/mini_codes/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ryven/main/Ryven.py", line 75, in run
    editor = MainWindow(editor_init_config, window_title, window_theme, flow_theme, parent=gui_parent)
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/mini_codes/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ryven/gui/main_window.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.import_nodes(path=abs_path_from_package_dir('main/nodes/built_in/'))
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/mini_codes/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ryven/gui/main_window.py", line 340, in import_nodes
    self.session.register_nodes(nodes)
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/mini_codes/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ryvencore/Session.py", line 39, in register_nodes
    self.register_node(n)
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/mini_codes/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ryvencore/Session.py", line 46, in register_node
    node_class.build_identifier()
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/mini_codes/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ryvencore/Node.py", line 66, in build_identifier
    cls.identifier = prefix + cls.identifier
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

The error comes from file `Node.py`,source code below:

```py
    @classmethod
    def build_identifier(cls):
        """
        sets the identifier to class name if it's not set, and adds the identifier prefix
        """

        prefix = ''
        if cls.identifier_prefix is not None:
            prefix = cls.identifier_prefix + '.'

        if cls.identifier is None:
            cls.identifier = cls.__name__

        cls.identifier = prefix + cls.identifier

        # notice that we do not touch the identifier compatibility fields
```

Finally get by doing debug:

If the `cls.identifier` is `None`,the codes's logic is to set the cls's attribute `identifier` as cls's `__name__`: `identifier` also be `None` after the code `cls.identifier = cls.__name__`.

Why?I do the codes to test:

```py
class A():
    identiry: str = None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cls = A

    if cls.identiry is None:
        cls.identiry = "hello"

    print(cls.identiry)
```

Comes out:

```sh
>>>hello
```

Why not successful just when setting attribute in `Ryven`?
[image]

Comment: What is `cls.identifier`? An attribute? A property? I could not find it in the [repo](https://github.com/leon-thomm/Ryven/tree/master/ryven).

Comment: @deponovo a static attribute defined in [in the core](https://github.com/leon-thomm/ryvencore/blob/main/ryvencore/Node.py)

Comment: @nutrx thanks, was coming back to report the same :) It's an odd issue.

Comment: interesting. it's not deterministic, sometimes the first node works, the second crashes, sometimes the first already crashes, even though the line `cls.identifier = cls.__name__` is executed without error, it seems to have no effect

Comment: @HaoLan Would suggest to fill an issue in the respective [github page](https://github.com/leon-thomm/ryvencore/issues). Do you happen to be the developer @nutrx?

Comment: I also add an issue on ryven's github page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone runs into this: PySide2 seems broken on Python 3.10. Please use <=3.9 for now.

The issue was also reported on [GitHub](https://github.com/leon-thomm/Ryven/issues/87), Ryven 3.1.1 excludes Python 3.10